# $\frac{d}{dt}(P^t_aA)=A(t)P^t_aA$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and let $A:[a,b] \rightarrow M_m(\mathbb{R})$ be a continuous function. Then $$(a,b)\in t \rightarrow P^t_aA$$ is continously differentiable for all $t\in (a,b)$ and its derivative is given by $$\frac{d}{dt}(P^t_aA)=A(t)P^t_aA$$

Prove the above theorem.

### My attempt:

$P^t_aA= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\int_{a}^{t} A(S_1)dS_1 \int_{a}^{t_1} A(S_2)dS_2...$

$= \mathbb{1}_m+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{t}\{\int_{a}^{S_1}\int_{a}^{S_{n-1}}A(S_1)...A(S_n)dS_n...dS_{n-1} ...\}$

$\frac{d}{dt}(P^t_aA)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt}(\int_{a}^{t}\{\int_{a}^{S_1}\int_{a}^{S_{n-1}}A(S_1)...A(S_n)dS_n...dS_{n-1} ...\}$

Not sure if I am on the right track.. can someone help me finish this?

Note... we are talking about the time-ordered exponential of $A$

Comment: What is $P$?   [some characters]

Comment: time-ordered exponential of $A$